# MJPG streaming with audio

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, mjpeg

I have a program on the server side that keeps generating a series of JPEG files, and I want to play these files on the client browser as a video stream, with a desired frame rates (this video should be playing while the new JPEG files are being generated). Meanwhile, I have a wav file that is handy and I want to play this wav file in the client side, when the streaming video is being played.

Is there anyway to do it? I have done a plenty of research but can't find a satisfactory solution -- they are either just for video streaming or just for audio streaming.

I know mjpg-streamer at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/ is capable of playing streaming videos in MJPG format from JPEG files, but it doesn't look like that it can play streaming audios.

I am very new to this area, so more detailed explanation will be extremely appreciated. Thank you so much!!!

P.S. a solution/library in C++ is preferred but anything else would help as well. I am working on linux.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. The proper way of doing it is to use ffmpeg, libav and an RTMP server, such as red5.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

The browser should be able to do this natively, no? Firefox can do this certainly, if you simply give it the correct url of the streaming mjpeg source. The mjpeg stream should be properally formatted.